# Child div shadow not appearing

Tags: css, tailwind-css

Why won't the shadow appear for the `div` with `id="pin"`? I've tried wrapping it in a `div` and applying the shadow to the parent but that wasn't working either. How can I get the shadow to appear?

This is the HTML I have from my Tailwind playground.

```html
<div class="relative flex min-h-screen flex-col items-center overflow-hidden bg-gray-50 py-6 sm:py-12">
  <div id="note" class="w-40 h-40 bg-yellow-100 shadow-2xl p-4 flex flex-col items-center">
    <div id="pin" class="bg-red-500 shadow-2xl w-3 h-3 rounded-full"></div>
    <div>Content..</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Perhaps there's a versioning issue? I copied your code with a link to the latest Tailwind CDN and it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Explicitly like @ngtrthinh is referring to would be something in this ballpark:

```html
<div class=" flex min-h-screen flex-col items-center overflow-hidden bg-gray-50 py-6 sm:py-12">
  <div id="note" class="w-40 h-40 bg-yellow-100 shadow-2xl p-4 flex flex-col items-center">
    <div id="pin" class="bg-red-500 shadow-[0_4px_3px_1px_rgba(0,0,0,0.6)]  w-3 h-3 rounded-full"></div>
    <div>Content..</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can test this here: [Play Tailwind](https://play.tailwindcss.com/Vluam1uOBy)

Have a great day!

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and it works. The only problem is, the shadow is too small to be seen. To verify it you could make the circle bigger and try toggling the shadow on and off in your css devtool.

Just a side note: shadow color is by default using the color of the tag's text. This might also cause bad visibility on some background color.

Comment: I can see the shadow if I make the circle bigger and explicitly state the color is black. However, I want the shadow to appear when the circle is small.

Comment: You might want to use arbitrary value for the shadow and make it bigger (or bolder): https://tailwindcss.com/docs/drop-shadow#arbitrary-values